# Excel Macro to select cells and insert into a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro in Excel that lets me highlight a selection of cells (single column) and inset it into an string.

The string is going to be used in an SQL statement, but I am happy to do that, it is just getting the highlight part to work that I am struggling with.

I have found examples of how many cells I have selected, last number selected, etc. But not just a string of the selected cell values.

E.g.

> A1= value1
>     A2= Value2
>     A3= Value3

So when I highlight `A1:A3` and press ok the Array (if that is best) will contain

> "Value1 Value2 Value3"

Any help or advice would be appreciated.  I have tried various searches so apologies if this has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

For a single column you can do this very quickly and simply with

```
StrIn = Join(Application.Transpose(Selection))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your column is Column A from rows 1 to 5:

```
Sub funString()
Dim stringVal As String
stringVal = ""

For i = 1 To 5
    Set cellVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)    
        stringVal = cellVal & " " & stringVal 
Next i

MsgBox (stringVal)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5) = stringVal 'prints onto cell (5,5)
End Sub
```

Modify i, j, and the column as necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment.

I have taken snippets from this and other solutions and came up with this which seems to do the job:

(Created a User Form- Excuse my workings, as it can probably be done smarter!)

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
UserForm1.RefEdit1.Text = Selection.Address
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim addr As String, rng, cell As Range, minimum As Double

Dim stringVal As String
Dim FullName As Variant

stringVal = ""

addr = RefEdit1.Value
Set rng = Range(addr)
minimum = WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)

For Each cell In rng
stringVal = cell.Value & " " & stringVal

Next cell
Dim txt As String
Dim FullNameSpaces As Variant
Dim FullNameHyphens As Variant

txt = stringVal

FullNameSpaces = Split(txt, " ")
FullNameHyphens = Join(FullNameSpaces, "', '")
FullNameHyphens = Left(FullNameHyphens, Len(FullNameHyphens) - 3)

stringVal = "Select * From TABLE WHERE FIELD IN ('" & FullNameHyphens & ")"

Unload Me

MsgBox (stringVal)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

---